# Automatic rollback if program exits

Tags: mysql, transactions

The [MySQL documentation on transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) seems to be lacking one important piece of informaton, and that is my question:

If a transaction is in progress and the client disconnects (in my case, if PHP `exit`s or `die()`s or simply reaches the end of the code), is the transaction rolled back, or committed?

I'm assuming rolled back, but that could be a massive problem if the assumption is wrong...

If it makes any difference, all the tables are using the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the normal case, client disconnect will cause a rollback in MySQL. However, if your server goes down unexpectedly (e.g. hardware or network failure), it may take a bit of time before disconnecting your client. From the manual, 28800 seconds is the default value the server will wait for activity before rolling back your transaction.

You can adjust the [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) setting on your server or the [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) property to shorten this though.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation :)

Comment: I spent an entire day figuring out why my PHPUnit tests with transactions are "hanging". Turns out the `wait_timeout` setting in MySQL was set into a number which felt equal to eternity.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page: http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Using-Transactions-In-MySQL-Part-1

"...it is interesting to note that if you begin a transaction, but exit the session before issuing a COMMIT or ROLLBACK, MySQL does *not* perform an automatic COMMIT; instead, it issues a ROLLBACK"

I did a few test to confirm this and here are the results for each of the scenarios. (note: when the page exits without COMMIT, mysql rollbacks automatically):

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO log SET temp = 'test'");

exit("Exit\n");  // Auto rollback;

die( "Die\n");  // Auto rollback;

throw new Exception("Exception\n"); // Auto rollback;

try {
    throw new Exception("Exception\n");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught\n"; // Committed;
}

require_once('invalid_file.php'); // Auto rollback;

mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Comment: I noticed this behaviour after I accidentally forgot to `COMMIT` before returning the AJAX response to a particularly complex query. Understandably I kicked myself.

Comment: It should be // Auto rollback in catch statement instead of //committed